# How to remove header from the curl response

Tags: magento-1.9

Is that any way to remove headers from the cURL response..

My code is,

```
$curl = new Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl(); 
$curl->setConfig(array('timeout' => 30));
$url = "http://example.com/";
$curl->write(Zend_Http_Client::GET, $url, '1.0');
$data = $curl->read();
if($data == false)
{
    echo false;
}else{
    $data = preg_split('/^r?$/m', $data,2);
    print_r($data);
}
$curl->close();
```

And my output is,

```
Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Wed, 24 Jun 2015 09:33:56 GMT Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.19 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.19 Set-Cookie: ci_session=a%3A5%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%227d93b2c24eaeb72c3c449d3e953dd81e%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A9%3A%22127.0.0.1%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bb%3A0%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bi%3A1435138436%3Bs%3A9%3A%22user_data%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3B%7Db4227a2043de07a5fb1417f9014db30720c8c928; expires=Wed, 24-Jun-2015 11:33:56 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/ Content-Length: 1053 Content-Type: text/html Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [mobile_image] => ./admin_styles/image/mobile_app/accomodation.jpg ) [1] => [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [mobile_image] => ./admin_styles/image/mobile_app/accomodation.jpg ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 3 [mobile_image] => ./admin_styles/image/mobile_app/accomodation.jpg ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 4 [mobile_image] => ./admin_styles/image/mobile_app/accomodation.jpg ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 5 [mobile_image] => ./admin_styles/image/mobile_app/accomodation.jpg ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 6 [mobile_image] => ./admin_styles/image/mobile_app/accomodation.jpg ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 7 [mobile_image] => ./admin_styles/image/mobile_app/accomodation.jpg ) ) )
```

And I want to remove the headers in the output.. 
is that any default function  to remove curl headers in magento like `CURLOPT_HEADER` in php

Thanks

Comment: This question is better geared for StackOverflow or such as it is PHP/CURL specific.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142869/how-to-remove-http-headers-from-curl-response

Comment: @B00MER I have no problem at PHP/CURL....But in magento we are using `Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl()` ,so is that any format for removing header like read/write...

Comment: Zend_Http_Response::extractBody($data) is how to parse curl response the magento way

Comment: @james.c.funk  Thanks. This solution works for me Zend_Http_Response::extractBody($data)